# Handler meaning

Tags: android, multithreading, service, handler

I think that handlers in android are tools to get different objects that are in a Thread and move it to another Thread for example UI thread in android.
Is it true? 
**Sorry for my knowledge** :)

Thanks!

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html),

> A Handler allows you to send and process Message and Runnable objects
>   associated with a thread's MessageQueue. Each Handler instance is
>   associated with a single thread and that thread's message queue. When
>   you create a new Handler, it is bound to the thread / message queue of
>   the thread that is creating it -- from that point on, it will deliver
>   messages and runnables to that message queue and execute them as they
>   come out of the message queue.